# Figcaption Makes Figures Vertical, I need them Horizontal

Tags: html, css

```html
<figure>
<img src="imgsrc1.png" alt="image">
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
<img src="imgsrc2.png" alt="image">
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
<img src="imgsrc3.png" alt="image">
<figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<!--As you can see it makes the images aligned Vertically--!>
```

I have been attempting to have a part of my website where I have three images horizontally aligned with captions. I have decided to use the figure tag which has them horizontally aligned, however, when I add a figcaption they become vertically aligned (stacked on top of each other). This is not what I want and I don't understand why the figcaption does this. Can anyone tell me how to keep the images horizontally aligned?

Comment: How do you fix what? You've posted a single sentence. Please read [ask] and post a [mcve] thanks

Comment: I have made the post clearer and longer.

Comment: We still need the [mcve]

Comment: I have added a snippet of code similar to that of what I have in my website.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the code, this shows that your use of the figure element is wrong. Each img/figcaption pair should be wrapped in a figure. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/figure Then use your browser dev tools inspect facility to look at the CSS applied to a figure element and you will see it has display: block. If you want them inline then you could set display: inline-block, or probably better for responsiveness etc to look into having an overall wrapper element and display: flex or grid on that.